# Guidance in writing two classes for a staff directory given example code

Tags: php, oop

I am struggling with an assignment.

I have been given a file and told to write the classes and corresponding functions to run the example code given to me.

I'm not that familiar with Php. I'm after a little guidance to help me get started.

Here is the example code and associated output that I have been given:

```
<?php
include('Directory.php');
include('Entry.php');

$directory = new Directory("Staff Directory");

echo $directory->getName(); // prints "Staff Directory"

$billEntry = new Entry(array(
    "First Name" => "Bill",
    "Last Name" => "Hen",
    "Phone Number" => "876-330-1111",
    "Department" => "IT"
));

$directory->addEntry($billEntry);

$results = $directory->findByLastName("Hen");

foreach ($results as $result) {
    print $result->getPhoneNumber();
}
// the above prints "876-330-1111"
$stanEntry = new Entry(array(
    "First Name" => "Stanley",
    "Last Name" => "Little",
    "Phone Number" => "112-334-5565",
    "Department" => "IT"
));

$directory->addEntry($stanEntry);
echo $directory->getNumberOfEntries(); // prints 2
echo $directory; // should print all of the information in the directory so far, including the directory title
echo count($directory->findByDepartment("IT")); // prints 2
$directory->removeEntry($billEntry);
echo $directory->getNumberOfEntries(); // prints 1
```

Here is what I think the getName() function should look like for the Directory class:

```
public function getName() {
    $this->name;
}
```

Would that be enough to make that function work? If not, what am I missing?

I mainly need help with how to deal with the entry storage.  I figure it uses an array, but how?

I've tried many web resources, but now, I am stuck.  Please help out a newbie. I'd really appreciate it.

EDIT: Finished product

```
<?php
class DirectoryA {
    private $name;
    private $entries;

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;   
    }

    public function __toString() {
            $print = $this->name;
            $print .= "\n--------------------";
        foreach ($this->entries as $entry) {
            $print .= sprintf("\nFirst Name: %s\n", $entry->getFirstName());
            $print .= sprintf("Last Name: %s\n", $entry->getLastName());
            $print .= sprintf("Phone Number: %s\n", $entry->getPhoneNumber());
            $print .= sprintf("Department: %s", $entry->getDept());
            $print .= "\n--------------------------";
        }
        return $print;
     }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function addEntry($person) {
        $this->entries[] = $person;
    }

    public function findByLastName($lastName) {
        $matches = array();
        foreach ($this->entries as $entry) {
            if ($entry->getLastName() == $lastName)
                $matches[] = $entry;
        }
        return $matches;
    }

    public function findByDepartment($depart) {
        $depMatch = array();
        foreach ($this->entries as $entry) {
            if ($entry->getDept() == $depart)
                $depMatch[] = $entry;
        }
        return $depMatch;
    }

    public function getNumberOfEntries() {
        $numOfEntries = 0;
        foreach ($this->entries as $entry) {
            $numOfEntries += $entry;
        }
        return $numOfEntries;
    }

    public function removeEntry($person) {
        unset($this->entries[0]);
    }
}//ends DirectoryA class
```

/*----------------------------------------------*/

```
<?php

class Entry {
    private $lN;
    private $fN;
    private $phone;
    private $dept;

    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->fN = $data['First Name'];
        $this->lN = $data['Last Name'];
        $this->phone = $data['Phone Number'];
        $this->dept = $data['Department'];
    }

    public function getFirstName() {
        return $this->fN;
    }

    public function getPhoneNumber() {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    public function getLastName(){
        return $this->lN;
    }

    public function getDept() {
        return $this->dept;
    }

}
```

I will say this exercise definitely helped me understand classes and scope. I hope it can some way somehow help someone else out too.

Comment: If the name is in `$this->name` (member variable `name` in Directory class), then you can just do `return $this->name;` to return it, so echo can print it.

Comment: sweet thanks!, forgot about that. Could you tell me if that'll actually work for my purpose too?

Comment: I don't know what your actual purpose it, but if you want to print it outside of the class (or anything else like processing), you need to return it, that's what the `return` keyword is for.

Comment: I don't see OOP in your example, I see procedural programming with structs and ADTs implemented via classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entry entity and directory classes could look something like this:

```
<?php
namespace Foo;

class Person
{
    private $first_name;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        if(isset($data['First Name']))
            $this->first_name = $data['First Name'];
    }

    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->first_name;
    }
}

class People
{
    // This will be an array of persons
    private $people;

    public function addPerson(Person $person)
    {
        $this->people[] = $person;
    }

    public function findByFirstName($first_name)
    {
        $results = array();
        if(count($this->people)) {
            foreach($this->people as $key => $person) {
                if($person->getFirstName() == $first_name) {
                    $results[] = $person;
                }
            }
        }

        return $results;
    }

}

$foo = new Person(array(
    "First Name" => "Foo",
));

var_dump($foo);

$people = new People;
$people->addPerson($foo);

var_dump($people->findByFirstName('Foo'));
```

That should give you a good start.

To print an entry:

```
function entry_to_string($entry)
{
    $o  = sprintf("First Name: %s\n",   $entry->getFirstName());
    $o .= sprintf("Last Name: %s\n",    $entry->getLastName());
    $o .= sprintf("Department: %s\n",   $entry->getDepartment());
    $o .= sprintf("Phone Number: %s\n", $entry->getPhoneNumber());

    return $o;
}
```

Comment: @PalChet Please share your finished implementation.

Comment: I am almost there, the only error/problem I have now are the first 2 lines after I include the files. my getName function doesn't work (nothing is printing) and my __toString function doesn't work in the same way. Could you help me with this? Also line 33 is why I need the __toString function

Comment: I might open up a new question for this but here it is: How do I output what is inside my array (containing first name, last name, etc...) using my __toString method? Is that possible? If it's not, what do I need to do?

Comment: I've added a string function above.  You could place that in the entries __toString method, and swap `$entry` for `$this`.  You could loop through your entries in the directory and print each entry for the directory's string representation.

Comment: I included my finished product in an edit. Thanks for all your help. You are awesome! Feel free to criticize ;P

Comment: I can see a few problems with your answer that you've added to your original post.  Perhaps it would be better to create an answer with your answer.

Comment: when I have more time, I certainly will. I fixed the toString method as well. Once again, thanks for all your help.